# IE9 and :after/:hover Css property causing page to grow

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, css-selectors, pseudo-element

According to microsoft, IE8 and IE9 support the :after selector. I use this selector to force elements to have the proper height, if all the elements inside are floated. This allows backgrounds to show up properly, without having to specify a set height.

My after code typically looks like this:

```
.after:after{
    content: '.';
    height:0;
    line-height: 0;
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

So now to the bug. When I added a few :after to my page at https://spartanstats.com/reach-stats-gamertag and I hover over each of the li elements in the middle of the page, IE9 grows the page by one line each time.

EDIT:

Upon further investigation the :hover property on each of the dynamically generated li elements is seemingly the root cause of the problem. Removing the hover code for the li's fixes the problem. Of course this isn't the fix I was hoping for. I'll keep investigating.

Currently I'm lost in finding the solution to this issue. But I know my users will potentially hate the site when it starts growing out of control!

Comment: well nobody seems interested in this problem, thats fine. I have a shitty solution (remove hover) that i'll implement with ie9 until I find a more suitable shim/fix. Thanks

Comment: looks like the url is down. can you post jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using

```
content: '';
```

instead of

```
content: '.';
```

Having a character in your after element and setting it to use

```
display: block;
visibility: hidden;
```

will still cause the element to take up space on the page unlike when you use:

```
display: none;
```

My guess is that even though you're setting the height of the :after element to 0, the . in the element is causing Internet Explorer to render an unwanted height.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this issue myself. It may be related to [this issue](http://blog.brianrichards.net/post/6721471926/ie9-hover-bug-workaround)

Apply `min-height: 0%` to the containing element.